# Magnific Popup fails to work with multiple galleries on a page

Tags: magnific-popup

I am using magnific popup on a new website that i am building but i am running into a problem getting it to work when multiple galleries on the same page.

I'm using wordpress, Slick Slider to display a slider full of thumbnails and when one of the thumbnails is clicked it should open the larger version of the image in the Magnific Popup.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="media-carousel slick-initialized slick-slider" id="carousel-links">
<div class="slick-list draggable" tabindex="0">
    <div class="slick-track" style="opacity: 1; width: 1152px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
        <div class="slick-slide slick-active" data-slick-index="0" style="width: 288px;">
            <div class="standard_media_element media_title">
                <a href="image1-large.jpg" title="" class="gallery-item" data-effect="mfp-move-horizontal">
                <img src="image1.jpg" alt="" class="standard-image"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-slide slick-active" data-slick-index="1" style="width: 288px;">
            <div class="standard_media_element media_title">
                <a href="image2-large.jpg" title="" class="gallery-item" data-effect="mfp-move-horizontal">
                <img src="image2.jpg" alt="" class="standard-image"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-slide slick-active" data-slick-index="2" style="width: 288px;">
            <div class="standard_media_element media_title">
                <a href="image3-large.jpg" title="" class="gallery-item" data-effect="mfp-move-horizontal">
                <img src="image3.jpg" alt="" class="standard-image"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slick-slide slick-active" data-slick-index="3" style="width: 288px;">
            <div class="standard_media_element media_title">
                <a href="image4-large.jpg" title="" class="gallery-item" data-effect="mfp-move-horizontal">
                <img src="image4.jpg" alt="" class="standard-image"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a site.js file that contains all of the javascript for my site in it.  I'm calling magnific popup using the following function.  I've added some extra stuff in it to add effects.

```
jQuery('#carousel-links').each(function() {
jQuery(this).magnificPopup({
    delegate: 'a',
    type: 'image',
    tClose: 'Close (Esc)',
    tLoading: '',
            preload: [1,4],
    gallery:{
        enabled:true,
        tPrev: 'previous',
        tNext: 'next',
        tCounter: '%curr% of %total%'
    },
    image: {
        verticalFit: true,
        titleSrc: function(item) {
        return item.el.attr('title') + ' &middot; <a class="image-source-link" href="'+item.src+'" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-file-image-o"></i> open original</a>';
        }
    },
    closeBtnInside: false,
    closeOnContentClick: false,
    mainClass: 'mfp-zoom-in',
    removalDelay: 300, //delay removal by X to allow out-animation
    callbacks: {
        lazyLoad: function (item) {
            console.log(item); // Magnific Popup data object that should be loaded
        },
        beforeOpen: function() {
            jQuery('#carousel-links a').each(function(){
                jQuery(this).attr('title', $(this).find('img').attr('alt'));
            }); 
        },
        open: function() {
            //overwrite default prev + next function. Add timeout for css3 crossfade animation
            jQuery.magnificPopup.instance.next = function() {
                var self = this;
                self.wrap.removeClass('mfp-image-loaded');
                setTimeout(function() { jQuery.magnificPopup.proto.next.call(self); }, 120);
            }
            jQuery.magnificPopup.instance.prev = function() {
                var self = this;
                self.wrap.removeClass('mfp-image-loaded');
                setTimeout(function() { jQuery.magnificPopup.proto.prev.call(self); }, 120);
            }
        },
        imageLoadComplete: function() { 
            var self = this;
            setTimeout(function() { self.wrap.addClass('mfp-image-loaded'); }, 16);
        }
    }
 });
 });
```

I have the same exact HTML code building different galleries outputting on the same page and for some reason the first carousel with lightbox works great.  But for whatever reason, the second gallery does not work.  The carousel works fine, but Magnific Popup does not fire.  When i click on one of the thumbnails, it opens the larger image in the browser window.

I tested my js function by adding a "`console.log("clicked");`" after the .each.  I see the console that the thumbnail is being clicked and that part is working.

Any idea how i can get the multiple sliders to work on my page?

I've tried the example from the documentation for the multiple galleries by removing everything from the function and making it as barebone as possible.  I get the same result, the first lightwindow works but the second one does not.

I'm not seeing any js errors on the console either.

**UPDATE #1**
This isn't an ideal solution, but i did find a way to make this work.  I had to use unique IDs on each slider in order to get the lightbox to work if multiple sliders were on the same page using the same ID value.  In this case, I was using #carousel-links for all of the sliders.  I guess you can't share the same ID for sliders across the board and get this lightbox to work?

I also moved the javascript code to be right after the carousel in the module template page.  I removed it for now from my site.js file.

I'm not looking for a way to optimize the code so i can put it in my site.js.  I'll try to grab that ID value by using the class on each carousel.  I'll report back if i can get that to work.

**UPDATE #2 - OMG**
Could the problem i was having when the lightbox only worked with the first instance of the lightbox be because i was an ID instead of a CLASS as my selector for the lightbox?  I changed to the CLASS and now they are all working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What fixed my problem is I changed the selector from the ID to a class on the same element.  This allowed for multiple galleries on the same page to work together with no problem.

Comment: I'm surprised no-one jumped on this to help you out. Thank you for posting your answer.